# How to get value from jquery which come from api controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Hello I have a web API controller which is returning an integer value and I don't know how to get it in a jquery ajax function.
My API controller is following.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/tblProducts/{UserId}/CheckUserAvil")]
[ResponseType(typeof(int))]
public IHttpActionResult CheckUserAvil(string UserId)
{
    int Exist = db.CheckUserIdAvil(UserId);
    return Ok(Exist);
}
```

And my jquery code is given

```
$.getJSON("/api/tblProducts/" + Userid + "/CheckUserAvil", function (data) {

});
```

I don't know how to handle response I want Exist variable value which come from controller.
Please help me.

UPDATE
My Stored Procedure Code is fallowing

```
USE [MakaAnOrderDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CheckUserIdAvil]    Script Date: 8/19/2018 1:18:30 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckUserIdAvil]
      @UserId nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @Exists INT

      IF EXISTS(SELECT @UserId
                        FROM tblUser
                        WHERE UserId = @UserId  )
      BEGIN
            SET @Exists = 1
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
            SET @Exists = 0
      END

      RETURN @Exists
END
GO
```

And it is workin well in Sql But in Api.It is returing -1 all the time

Comment: The variable `data` in the callback function will contain the value of `Exist`.

Comment: [Web API and JQuery to do GET or POST Data](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/678138/MVC-using-Web-API-and-JQuery-to-GET-or-POST-Data)

Answer (score 0):

the callback argument `data` will have the data you seek.

One suggestion would be to have the action return a model that makes the returned data easier to understand.

For example, the following uses an anonymous object to hold the data.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/tblProducts/{UserId}/CheckUserAvil")]
[ResponseType(typeof(int))]
public IHttpActionResult CheckUserAvil(string UserId) {
    int exist = db.CheckUserIdAvil(UserId);
    var model = new {
        Exist = exist
    };
    return Ok(model);
}
```

the client will then extract the desired data from the response in the callback function

```
$.getJSON("/api/tblProducts/" + Userid + "/CheckUserAvil", function (data) {
    var exist = data.Exist;
    console.log("Exist: " + exist);
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi Sir ,It's working well but one more problem i am facing in it i made a stored procedure of checking User Avilable in table and procedure is working fine in SQL server but in api appliction it's returning -1 all time I am going  to Update my question with strored Procedure,Please help me